# How to resolve Flowtype error with React Native out of the box?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flowtype

I am preparing to use React Native for a company project. However, flowtype is giving me error out of the box, and the errors come from `react-native` library (and some other libraries), so I have little to no control over. The errors are about some type definitions not accessible, and there are about 200 of them.

I only use the standard `.flowconfig` as follow

```
[ignore]
; We fork some components by platform
.*/*[.]android.js

; Ignore "BUCK" generated dirs
<PROJECT_ROOT>/\.buckd/

; Ignore unexpected extra "@providesModule"
.*/node_modules/.*/node_modules/fbjs/.*

; Ignore duplicate module providers
; For RN Apps installed via npm, "Libraries" folder is inside
; "node_modules/react-native" but in the source repo it is in the root
.*/Libraries/react-native/React.js
.*/Libraries/react-native/ReactNative.js
```

and it already includes some `ignore` modules.

I also notice that flow is very unstable, i.e. initially it reports no errors, and then, without no to little code change, it reports hundreds of errors from elsewhere where the code change does not happen (no extra libraries installed or imported).

The first question is, how can I avoid these errors and make flow output more meaningful for development.

The second and more general question is what is the convention for using flow.

If you find this question too general or misleading, please comment so I can make it better, because I am just as confused.

I am using
- React Native 0.44
- React 16.0.0-alpha-6
- Flow 0.46.0